# How to save authorization cookies in webView? (Android Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, webview

I searched answer, but not find it. Tell me please, how to save authorization cookies in webView? (Android Kotlin)?
I try to make

```
     webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                      override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {

               if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {   
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
} else {
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
}
            }
        }
```

But it is no always to work.